# Flutter BLoC `buildWhen` property

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I get a `_CastError`  error at the last line of this piece of code

```dart
BlocBuilder buildUsernameField() {
  return BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
    buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current && current is EditingUserInfo,
    builder: (context, state) => TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
      controller: TextEditingController(
          text: (state as EditingUserInfo).username.value),
```

saying that

```
I/flutter (26787): The following _CastError was thrown building BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (26787): _BlocBuilderBaseState<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>#25b87):
I/flutter (26787): type 'Success' is not a subtype of type 'EditingUserInfo' in type cast
```

So what's happening is that it tries to build that widget when I am in another state (success). But in the `buildWhen` parameter, I specified that the widget should only build when the state is `EditingUserInfo`.

So as far as I understand, this error should not happen.

Here's my `ProfileState` :

```dart
part of 'profile_bloc.dart';

abstract class ProfileState extends Equatable {
  const ProfileState();
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ProfileInitial extends ProfileState {}

class EditingUserInfo extends ProfileState {
  final Username username;
  final Bio bio;
  final PhotoUrl photoUrl;
  final City city;
  final FormzStatus status;

  const EditingUserInfo({
    this.username = const Username.pure(),
    this.bio = const Bio.pure(),
    this.photoUrl = const PhotoUrl.pure(),
    this.city = const City.pure(),
    this.status = FormzStatus.pure,
  });

  EditingUserInfo copyWith({Username username, Bio bio, PhotoUrl photoUrl, City city, FormzStatus status}){
    return EditingUserInfo(
      username: username ?? this.username,
      bio: bio ?? this.bio,
      photoUrl: photoUrl ?? this.photoUrl,
      city: city ?? this.city,
      status: status ?? this.status,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [username, bio, photoUrl, city];
}

class Loading extends ProfileState {}

class Error extends ProfileState {
  final String message;

  const Error({this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

class Success extends ProfileState {
  final String message;

  const Success({this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

Comment: Show your state file `ProfileState` & classes that extend it.

Comment: I updated the post with my ProfileState class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still have to check that the state variable is the proper state.  The state is checked EVERY time it is changed, so the state variable can still be a different state, it just doesn't rebuild unless the buildWhen conditions are true.

```
BlocBuilder buildUsernameField() {
return BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current && current is EditingUserInfo,
builder: (context, state) {
 if(state is EditingUserInfo) {
  return TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
  controller: TextEditingController(
      text: state.username.info)
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, si it means that I did not understand the `buildWhen` and `builder` fields quite well. So far, I thought that the widget returned in `builder` would build itself when and only when a boolean condition specified in `buildWhen` would be true. But what you're showing to me now is that what I thought is wrong. The widget should be returned not it the `builder` but in the `buildWhen` to be built only when the condition is true. Is that right ?

Comment: Nope I was wrong.  What you have is mostly right,  but in builder method, you still have to check to make sure it is the proper state.  The BlocBuilder still checks EVERY state change, which means the 'state' variable can still be a different state, it just doesn't rebuild unless it's in that state.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: I see, but what's the purpose of the `buildWhen` field ? Because the name suggests that the whole point of this property is to check when the builder function should run :O

Comment: It is.  Which means the builder will only rebuild the widget when your condition is true, but it still "checks" all of the state changes.   Just make sure you're returning false on all other conditions.

Comment: but the builder method need widget to be returned. which is not the case in ur answer;

Comment: This is an extremely late update, I fixed the answer.  I missed the return before the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clear answer to your questioning user54517 :

`buildWhen` will prevent your widget to rebuild if the bloc state changes, but it will not prevent it if the framework rebuilds it for any other reason (for instance, if one of its parents need a rebuild...).

That's why you still need to check the state in the builder method.

Source: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1413#issuecomment-655568783

Answer (score 0):

The `buildWhen` condition is not considered the first time the widget is built. It's purpose is to avoid all succesive builts.

In your case, inside `builder` you could add the following condition to solve the problem:

```
builder: (context, state) { 
  if (state is! EditingUserInfo) {
    return Container();
  }
  return TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
    controller: TextEditingController(
        text: (state as EditingUserInfo).username.value),
```